# How to get an instance from a serializer in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to get an instance from own serializer

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):

    serializer.save(slug=utils.unique_slug_generator(**serializer.validated_data),user_profile=self.request.user)
```

but didn't work because in unique_slug_generator i try to access to title of instance

```
ModelClass = instance.__class__
qs_exists = ModelClass.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()
```

Error : unique_slug_generator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'

Comment: Are you talking about Django Rest Framework serializers?

Comment: Yes @TobiasErnst

Comment: Based on the serializer data, how do you determine which model instance you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add transaction before perform create. And raise exception to rollback database if have anything not valid.

```
from django.db import transaction
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        with transaction.atomic():
            obj = serializer.save()
            # validate anything you want, if not valid, raise exception and transaction will back before serializer.save. So nothing happen
            if not utils.unique_slug_generator(**serializer.validated_data):
                raise exceptions.ValidationError('not valid')
            obj.slug=utils.unique_slug_generator(**serializer.validated_data)
            obj.user_profile = self.request.user
            obj.save()
```

Hoop this help

Answer (score 2):

Usually you can create an instance by typing:

```
serializer = Serializer(**validated_data)
```

Then use `serializer.is_valid()` to check whether validated_data is valid.

After that, use `serializer.save()` to save the model.

To get a dictionary, use `serializer.data`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you can we get an instance without create it ? because that what i want

Comment: What are the reasons about not creating an instance?

Comment: Firstly i need to check if they have products with actual slug if not then i will save instance